# Getting error "-[NSThread threadDictionary]: message sent to deallocated instance"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, lldb

Sometime after writing code to my project, I noticed the debugger would pause my application and put `lldb` in the console and couldn't let me continue. I used `NSZombies` and I got this message : "`-[NSThread threadDictionary]: message sent to deallocated instance`". I have looked around but couldn't find any help what is causing this. When I print the backtrace I get:

```
thread #17: tid = 0x7886f, 0x0000000180f7ab40 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 700, stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x180f7ab40)
frame #0: 0x0000000180f7ab40 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 700
frame #1: 0x0000000180e78c5c CoreFoundation`_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
frame #2: 0x00000001860536dc UIFoundation`+[NSStringDrawingTextStorageSettings threadSpecificStringDrawingTextStorageSettings:] + 64
frame #3: 0x000000018604900c UIFoundation`+[NSString(NSStringDrawing) typesetterBehavior] + 32
frame #4: 0x000000018604a6d4 UIFoundation`__NSStringDrawingEngine + 244
frame #5: 0x000000018604a4d0 UIFoundation`-[NSString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) drawWithRect:options:attributes:context:] + 176
frame #6: 0x00000001860eb564 UIKit`-[UILabel _drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:] + 3856
frame #7: 0x000000018615e8f0 UIKit`-[UILabel drawTextInRect:] + 544
frame #8: 0x000000018615e678 UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 368
frame #9: 0x0000000183a92230 QuartzCore`-[CALayer drawInContext:] + 260
frame #10: 0x0000000183a7c8b4 QuartzCore`CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 2432
frame #11: 0x0000000183b94360 QuartzCore`___ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev_block_invoke + 52
frame #12: 0x0000000183a7ba90 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::display_() + 1368
frame #13: 0x0000000183a5d7b0 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 228
frame #14: 0x0000000183a5d49c QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 44
frame #15: 0x0000000183a5cac0 QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
frame #16: 0x0000000183a5c820 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 500
frame #17: 0x0000000183a8bbd4 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::release_thread(void*) + 236
frame #18: 0x0000000180bda1e0 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_tsd_cleanup + 584
frame #19: 0x0000000180bd9d58 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_exit + 136
frame #20: 0x0000000180bd953c libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 1296
frame #21: 0x0000000180bd9020 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 4
```

Any help to find out whats going on will help tremendously!

Comment: My guess: you're doing something that causes UI updates on a background thread.  I suggest reviewing your code and making sure that anything that touches a UI element is moved to the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the problem was I had a label with a weak reference. I was hiding it for to long and it seems the garbage collection cleaned in up. So when I tried to send data to it, it was already dealloc.

Answer (score -3):

Somewhere you are calling an instance method of any class and class object is nil.

Comment: Sending to nil is OK.  Sending to a non-nil reference that was deallocated is not.